# Is passing an address from if constexpr block always guaranteed to be valid outside the "context"?

Tags: c++, constexpr

Given this code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>

template <typename T>
void bar(T* t_ptr=nullptr){
    if constexpr(!std::is_same<T, void>()){
        std::cout << *t_ptr << "\n";
    } else {
        std::cout << "Ptr is null" << "\n";
    }
    
}


template<typename T>
void foo(){
    T* t_ptr = nullptr;
    if constexpr(!std::is_same<T, void>()){
        T t{42};
        t_ptr = &t;
    }
    bar(t_ptr);
}

int main(){
    foo<int>();
    foo<double>();
    foo<void>();
}
```

see also here https://godbolt.org/z/bEof7Pc4v

As far as I understand, passing the pointer to `bar` is valid, as the "context" created with {} is just for signaling which parts of the code should be executed and does not create an actual context. From the assembly it also appears that way, there are no remains of such a separate context. Is this correct or am I missing something?

Comment: It appears that you're asking whether `if constexpr` creates a scope and triggers destruction of objects created within?

Comment: *passing the pointer to bar* and there I go looking through the code for a function pointer. No, it is a pointer passed *to* `bar`. English is such a stupid language. Passing the pointer is fine. Using the value it points at... that's another kettle of fish.

Comment: @user4581301: Reading the value (which is an address) of a dangling pointer is, in fact, not fine according to the Standard.  It's implementation-defined behavior.  https://eel.is/c++draft/conv.lval#3.3

Comment: Note that I'm not talking about *dereferencing* the pointer, just reading its value.  Which is required for pass-by-value function parameters.

Comment: Actually, it does seem that you're missing something: undefined behavior. The pointer gets initialized with the address of an object that goes out of scope and gets destroyed. Then dereferenced. Hillarity ensues.

Comment: You have dangling pointer

Comment: I'm going to have to go through the implications of that carefully, @Ben . That's reading like you won't be able to safely even copy an object containing a dangling pointer on some systems.

Comment: @user - We have seen CPUs with [dedicated address registers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Motorola_68020#Architecture) that validated a loaded pointer against known segment limits. (Little risk for stack variables, but free'd heap blocks could have gone away).

Answer (score 1):

There's no special casing for `if constexpr` that makes it "not create an actual context".  The controlled statement of your constexpr if is a *compound-statement*.  Any *compound-statement* creates a block scope.

> A compound statement defines a block scope

- https://eel.is/c++draft/stmt.block#2

Your variable `t` is introduced inside the block scope and doesn't exist after control flow exits the compound-statement.

Comment: That is very interesting as at least gcc and a few other compilers I tried do indeed differentiate between if (where it obviously doesn't compile) and `if constexpr` where it compiles flawlessly for this simple example. Anyways, relying on "implementation-defined" doesn't cut it for my project, unfortunately... Thanks

Comment: @Robin: Oh, there are indeed many differences between `if (condition)` and `if constexpr (condition)`.  But creation of a scope (which you called "context") is not one of those differences.